# Python loop for all possible contiguous combinations of entries in a column/array

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, while-loop, python-itertools

I have a column in a dataframe that looks like this.

```
df['ind']
**ind**
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4]
[3,4,5]
[4,5,6]
[5,6,7]
[6,7,8]
[7,8,9]
[8,9,10]
[1,2,3,4]
[2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5,6]
[4,5,6,7]
[5,6,7,8]
[6,7,8,9]
[7,8,9,10]
```

The output I would like to get is

```
index_1    index_2    index_3    index_4    index_5  ...  index_(N-1)    index_N
[1,2,3]    [2,3,4]    [3,4,5]    [1,2,3]    [1,2,3]       [2,3,4,5]     [3,4,5,6]
[4,5,6]    [5,6,7]    [6,7,8]    [4,5,6]    [4,5,6,7]     [6,7,8,9]     [7,8,9,10]
[7,8,9]    [8,9,10]     NA       [7,8,9,10]  [8,9,10]        NA            NA
```

Each three or four integer arrays are "one" entry in the column `df['ind']`. I want to get another df or a list of all possible contiguous combinations.

I've been able to make it work when only one length of the array is being considered. E.g. all entries with length 3 or all with length 4. This is simply by extracting the `i:j*4th` cell on 3 entry arrays or `i:j*5th` cell on 4 entry arrays.

```
df2 = []
def myfunc(data):
    bin_ = np.round(len(data) / 3)
    for i in range(3):
        temp = []
        for j in range(0,bin_):
            temp.append(data['ind'][i+(4*j)])
        df2.append(temp)
```

Comment: Is your problem the algorithm? You're writing about data frames, so are you looking for a solution within Pandas? In that case, tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Think of `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6,7]` as forming an arrow `[1,2,3] -> [4,5,6,7]`. Implicitly you have a directed graph and you are trying to find all chains in that digraph. A bfs seems natural.

Comment: `ind[0][-1]` value is `3`, right? will `ind[14][-1]` get  `10` ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ thats right

Comment: try : [ use the `ind[i][0]` & `ind[i][-1]` to loop through elements in `df['ind']` > make a list of adjacent pairs/index > use the pairs list to 'generate' the output. ]

Comment: @p._phidot_ I tried this with `ind[i].min()` & `ind[i].max()` which is as you are suggesting. For each i I'm able to get a pair but in the real data there are over 100 entries and each pair computed for a certain contiguous set will go in different directions at some point. E.g. in `ind_1` and `ind_2` there could be exact same entries between `[0:5]` and then different from `[6]` onwards.

Comment: That is what I meant by 'generate'. | Using the pairs list, fill up `index_1` with pair1(array1&array4), `index_2` with pair2 (array2&array5), `index_3` with pair3 (array3&array6) and so on... u'll get (say..) up to `index_60` filled up with 2 arrays.. | Then using the same pairs list, find the 3rd array for each `index_x` , if there is a match, fillup. if there is 2 (or more) match, duplicate `index_x` & append both, if there is no matching 3rd pair, put NA. | The pairs list `seeds` for the output generator..

Comment: `each pair computed for a certain contiguous set will go in different directions ` >> list all. if `array1` can be paired with`array3`,`array4`&`array7`, just list ALL as separate entries : eg `array1-array3`,`array1-array4`&`array1-array7`. | i'd prefer (but not actually recommending), to list the pairs with this format : [ pair#(runningNumber), head(value), tail(value), array1 position in df (index), array2 position in df (index) ] | I'm not really particular on the data format, as long as it can be used to load/generate the final list.. any pairs list data structure  should work just fine.